# Access VBA - To get data from Excel file stored in Sharepoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

I have the below code working for me provided the "Model_data.xlsm" file is stored in my hard drive. Is it possible if Access can get the data from "model_data.xlsm" stored in Sharepoint?

```
Private Sub Update_manu_data_Click()

Dim strXls As String

 strXls = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "Model_data.xlsm"
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12,   "Manufacturing_data", _
 strXls, True, "Combined!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is that the correct range name?

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for the edit of the mess i created.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes i dont have any problem running this code

Comment: So what's your question?  How to correct the path to sp location?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : I would like to know how to use "DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet" if Excel is in SP

Comment: I'd suggest navigating to the excel document within SharePoint, then copying the link directly from there -- unless there are permission issues you should be able to use this link regardless of whether or not it's on SharePoint.

Comment: or just set up a link to it?

Comment: So you mean to say to add the SP link of excel file to strXLS = CurrentProject.Path & chr(92) & "............"    ???

Comment: @Nathan_sav Since the Excel is inside the sub groups within the SP so i am unable to link the file with access. Access only links the main grps of SP and not the files within the sub grp

Comment: @AdityaIyer I mean when you see the file within the SP window, can you right click-->copy shortcut then use that as the reference?

Comment: @RyanL Access was not able to reference the copy shortcut link from SP, hence i had to find a workaround instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did find a workaround for this issue.

I Created a private function in access to download the Excel file from SP and then used the Transferspread sheet function to retrieve the data into access table.

Below is the code i used to download the Excel file in SP using access Vba

```
 Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Dim Ex As Object
  Dim Acc As Object
  Dim strXls As String


    Set Ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set Acc = Ex.Workbooks.Open("https://Sharepoint File link")

    Ex.Visible = False

    Acc.SaveAs "C:\Users\.......\test.xlsx"

    Acc.Close
    Ex.Quit

    strXls = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "C:\Users\.......\test.xlsx"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Tablename", _
    strXls, True, "Sheet(1)!"
 End Sub
```

Comment: May go without saying, but if you use the "Get Link" on SharePoint it will have a bunch of other stuff in the direct file URL. You may have to remove everything after the ".xlsx" (or whatever the file extension is) for it to open properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ConnectToExcel()
    Dim strSharePointPath As String
    Dim strExcelPath As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    ' Set the SharePoint path and Excel file name
    strSharePointPath = "http://yoursharepointurl.com/YourSharePointFolder/"
    strExcelPath = "YourExcelFile.xlsx"
    
    ' Build the connection string
    strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
        "DATABASE=" & strSharePointPath & ";" & _
        "LIST=" & strExcelPath & ";"
    
    ' Open the connection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open strConnectionString
    
    ' Open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", cnn
    
    ' Loop through the recordset and display the data
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    ' Clean up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```